# Facebook mobile iframe apps

Tags: facebook, mobile, facebook-apps, facebook-iframe

Quick question. I've created a number of iframe apps for Facebook which work fine on PC, Mac etc. But not on mobile devices. The icon just doesn't show when you visit the page. I assumed this was because I'd not defined a mobile site URL. I've now done this, but I'm still not seeing an icon. Am I missing the point?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what icon do you mean? if you defined your mobile site url correctly, your app shows up in the search field. if you're talking about a page tab, it's not possible at all. the mobile native apps don't support this. but you can always link to your mobile site url in newsfeed!

Comment: Thanks dude. Yeah I did mean the page tabs, so I think I'd got the wrong end of the stick. Thanks again for the info.